# Jquery UI multiple droppable outside of container still droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[image: Jquery UI droppable example]

Let's say I have the parent container (dotted), with overflow:hidden. Inside I have a div that exceeds the bounds of the container (gray, and red is the hidden part outside of container). This div is a Jquery UI droppable object.

**The Problem:**

The div part that is outside the container is still droppable. How do I stop this behaviour and only allow the part inside the container to be droppable?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give more context for the problem you're trying to solve? Why are you using droppables this way? Why can't just the dotted container be the droppable? We might be able to find a better solution (see the XY problem @ http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/256429).

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment about context, but here's a first pass at a possible solution at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/w9rJr/). I'm assuming that the parent (dotted) container is not a droppable.

```
$(".drag").draggable();
$(".child").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        /*
         * Check if draggable is inside the parent. This is a bit brute force, if
         * the parent itself is also a droppable it can also be checked by
         * listening for the 'over' event and setting a flag.
         */
        var pPos = $(".parent").offset(); // the parent container's position
        var dPos = ui.offset; // the current draggable's position

        // Can also add right/top/bottom contraints if required...?
        var withinParent = dPos.left > pPos.left;

        if (!withinParent) {
            // Move the draggable to its original position (or some safe spot)
            ui.draggable.animate(ui.draggable.data().draggable.originalPosition, "slow");
        }
    }
});
```

## Edit - Draggable Helper

If you're using a helper for your draggable, then this logic should go into the `revert` callback of the draggable. See the new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/ka9rG/).

There are a few assumptions I've made that may be wrong, so make sure to read the javascript comments! Good luck =)

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: function () {
        /*
         * Check if draggable is inside the parent. This is a bit brute force, if
         * the parent itself is also a droppable it can also be checked by
         * listening for the 'over' event and setting a flag.
         */

        // The parent container's position
        var pPos = $(".parent").offset();

        // The current draggable helper's position
        var dDraggable = this.data().draggable;
        var helper = dDraggable.helper;
        var dPos = helper.offset();

        /*
         * Can also add top and right/bottom contraints
         * if we only want to allow dragging onto droppable!
         * Will have to calculate right = left + width,
         * bottom = top + height. Also take into account possible
         * borders/padding/margin with jQuery outerWidth!
         */
        var withinParent = dPos.left > pPos.left;

        if (!withinParent) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // Move the draggable to the helper's position
            // NOTE: We're using offset here, so you may want to test this under various condition, e.g. relative/absolute parents!
            this.css(helper.offset());
            return false;
        }
    }
});
$(".child").droppable();
```

Comment: Hi Lebolo, You're on the right track. However I'm using a helper when dragging. As soon as it's dropped, it will immediately disappear so no animation will be seen.

When defying the draggable. I have the following: { revert: 'invalid' }. Is it possibly to manually trigger the invalid option when the helper is dropped outside the container and still on the draggable?

Comment: Hey Ilya, I think it is possible. See http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert, you can pass in a function "to determine whether the element should revert to its start position." I'll try to come up with an example later today, but you might be able to do the position calculation in this function and return true/false from it.

Comment: Hi @IlyaKarnaukhov, I added another solution. Make sure you read the javascript comments. Hope this helps (if it does, accept the answer ;)).